# Android multicolored progressbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have progress bar with custom drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="120"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="140">    
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
     android:fromDegrees="90"
     android:toDegrees="90">
  <shape
      android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:angle="0"
      android:type="sweep"
      android:thicknessRatio="20.0">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
   </shape>
  </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is there way to make this progress bar multicolored with different color on different progress? For example: 0-50 is white, 50-100 is green etc.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Two options I can think. 1) a gradient drawable (if you want that sort of effect). 2) create your own custom drawable; it's pretty simple to make a drawable to simply draw colors.

Comment: @Budius Can you post some exmaple please?

Comment: The base base is a Class that extends `Drawable` you override `onDraw` and make drawing calls directly to the canvas, like `canvas.drawRect(...)`. Here is the official docs on it https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html and you can easily Google to some tutorial

Comment: @Budius Thanks i will try